# Gradle task `connectedXXXAndroidTest` doesn't perform test cases under 1 specific directory

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-uiautomator, instrumented-test

The instrument test file structure in AD is like this:

```
com.companyname.propjectname
    integrationtest: 20 test cases
    systemtest:
        groupA: 30 test cases
    [x] groupB: 50 + test cases
```

And I used a custom build variant(XXX) for test purpose. After I perform tests with below gradle task command. It will generate a test report under `app/build/reports/AndroidTests/connected`, but weird thing is that it only collected 50 test cases result(integrationtest + systemtest\groupA) in the report. All test cases under groupB is not collected. I'm with iOS background, pretty new for Android, please advice what could be the reason if you guys met this issue before?

And BTW, per Google's doc, `--continue` keep your test ongoing even the previous test is failed.

`./gradlew connectedXXXAndroidTest --continue`